# From psd file to html without framework

Tags: html, css, screen-size

I have and psd file which I have to code in html and css.I have measured all margins and paddings with "line tool" on PS. After i type it in HTML and CSS it was not same as in the picture because of my screen size which is 1349 and the image of website is 1150px wide... So should i some math and 1349/1150 = 1.173 and multiply all my width, margins and paddings with this number to get the same result on the broswer? Or is there any smarter ways to make it exactly the same as it is in the picture?

How do front-end developers do this?
How do proffesionals do this when they get an image of design?

Comment: It really depends on the end-user's needs and the client's specifications. Pixel-perfect designs are not popular these days, compared to "responsive" designs which automatically fit to the user's screen size and more than often device type (e.g. desktop or mobile).

Comment: I got the assignement with an image. And I wonder what is the best way to solve it. Should I just messure with my eye? How do proffesionals do this when they get theire psd file and have to code css?

Comment: There's no "right or wrong" here. If you want it to be pixel-perfect, then you can use a measuring tool in an image editor to measure the original and compare to screenshots of the end result (since browsers's behavior may vary). If on the other hand you wish the result to better fit the user, you can use the original design as a template for guidelines.

Comment: I applied for front end developer job. And they sent me an image of design to test me. I don't want to screw up, so i want to know is it wrong to code it without messuring the acctual pixels.

Comment: By the way they asked to it without framework

Comment: By framework I assume they mean no Bootstrap. As for the measurements, you can either make two versions, pixel-perfect and responsive, or just contact them and ask for clarifications. Either way showing an initiative and explaining the reason behind your choice goes a long way with potential employers. Good luck :)